# Continuous functions in isolated points

Tags: analysis, continuity

Let $f:A \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Is the following equivalent?

$f$ is continuous for all $x_0\in A$ (Not necessarly a limit point) $\Leftrightarrow$ $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)=f(x_0)$ for all limit points $x_0 \in A$.

Comment: If $A$ were open and bounded and $x_0 = \inf \{x:x \in A\}$, $x_0$ is a limit point of $A$ but not in $A$, so $f(x_0)$ is not defined.

Comment: @Renard the question says for all limits points $x_0\in A$